# Magento 2.3.4 Page builder html wrapper

Tags: static-block, magento2.3.3, page-builder

I have upgraded from Magento EE `2.2.10` to `2.3.4`, I had some content blocks with custom `html` used for navigation links on various pages that were just  tags.  After upgrading If I try to edit a content block It is now wrapped in the html below.  This extra html breaks the CSS and JavaScript I had for the nav links.  Is there a way to remove this html wrapper?

```
<div data-content-type="row" data-appearance="contained" data-element="main">
    <div data-enable-parallax="0" data-parallax-speed="0.5" data-background-images="{}" data-element="inner" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex; flex-direction: column; background-position: left top; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; border-style: none; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 10px; padding: 10px;">
        <div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main" style="border-style: none; border-width: 1px; border-radius: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" data-decoded="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did this get edited to have Magento 2.2.3 in the title?

Comment: good question, I would have tagged it with 2.3.4 but that tag was not available to use

Comment: This affects `2.3.2-p2` as well

Comment: According to magento support this is what is supposed to be output and they did not give any way around it.

Comment: Me also facing this issue, any workarounds?

Comment: I ended up adding some JavaScript to remove some styles and classes.  Really not ideal but it works.

Comment: I finally figured this out. Each row that has it's own properties which by default is set to to 'Contained' which is 1170px with 10px padding and 10px bottom margin.   This s is automatically added to a block if you edit it the first time.  You can hover over row and then there will be a toolbar for the row.  Click the properties icon, select 'Full Bleed' and go down to the bottom and set the padding to 0px and bottom margin to 0px.  You mean need to re-index and/or clear cache.  Then it should be good, at last this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this out. Each row that has it's own properties which by default is set to to 'Contained' which is 1170px with 10px padding and 10px bottom margin. This is automatically added to a block if you edit it the first time. You can hover over row and then there will be a toolbar for the row. Click the properties icon, select 'Full Bleed' and go down to the bottom and set the padding to 0px and bottom margin to 0px. You mean need to re-index and/or clear cache. Then it should be good, at last this fixed it for me